# How to display image in ionic view?

Tags: angularjs, image, cordova, ionic-framework

i get my image in web service the result is :

```
imageJson:'http://localhost:40434/temp-photo/temp8530171778397183509baguette-baguette.jpg '
```

in my listEvent.html :

```
<div ng-repeat="evenement in evenementCategorieData">  
    <li> 


   <!-- http://localhost:40434/temp-photo/temp8530171778397183509baguette-baguette.jpg  -->

<a class="item item-thumbnail-left" href=""><img ng-if=evenement.imageJson ng-src=http://localhost/temp-photo/{{evenement.imageJson}}>{{evenement.titre_annonce}} {{evenement.texte_annonce}}</a></li>
```

but i dispaly this result :

[image]

the result of my web service:

```
{
adresse: "denden",
date_evenement: null,
idevenement: 27,
idsouscatego: 12,
iduser: null,
imageJson: "http//localhost40434/temp+photo/temp8530171778397183509baguette+baguettejpg=",
nbr_partici: 25,
prix: null,
texte_annonce: "rrrrrrrrrrrr",
titre_annonce: "Sib 2016"
},
```

my code of save my picture in BD:

```
facebookExample.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$cordovaOauth, $localStorage, $location,$ionicPopup,$state,$http, Camera) {

      $scope.getPhoto = function() {
        Camera.getPicture().then(function(imageURI) {
          console.log(imageURI);
          $scope.lastPhoto = imageURI;
          console.log("photo");
          console.log($scope.lastPhoto);
        }, function(err) {
          console.err(err);
        }, {
          quality: 75,
          targetWidth: 320,
          targetHeight: 320,
          saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        });
      };
```

after i defined the object for post:

var objInsc = new Object();
    objInsc.imageJson=$scope.lastPhoto;

my method post :
    $http.post('http://@ip:8080/elodieService/evenements/',objInsc).success(function(response, status, headers, config){
                 alert("SUCCESS ajout dans la table evenement!!");

```
             $http.get('http://@ip/elodieService/evenements/', { params: {fields: "texte_annonce,titre_annonce,adresse,imageJson",format:"json"} }).then(function(result) {

                 console.log("SUCCESS!"+result.data);
                 console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                 $scope.evenementData = result.data;

                });
```

what can i do?

Comment: so you dont want url to be `http://localhost:40434/temp-photo/temp8530171778397183509baguette-baguette.jpg` but `http://localhost/temp-photo/{{evenement.imageJson}}` ? What are you asking for ?

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget quotes, close your img element and change your location.

```
<img ng-if="evenement.imageJson" src="temp-photo/{{evenement.imageJson}}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `http://localhost/temp-photo/` in you `ng-src` since it is already declared in you `imageJson` object.

E.g.

`ng-src="{{evenement.imageJson}}"`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you check if the image exist or accessible using your browser? Also, is your app and image path use the server or not?

Comment: As I can see, your image has malformed format. It has a domain name and port connected to each other `(localhost40434)` without the `:` for port declaration.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, the problem is with the image path. The domain name which is connected to its port without the `:`. It should be `http://localhost:40434/temp+photo/temp8530171778397183509baguette+baguettejpg=`.

Answer (score 0):

Updte your code to

```
imageJson:'../temp-photo/temp8530171778397183509baguette-baguette.jpg '
```

Answer (score 0):

you should `encode` your URL while sending from backend and `decode` before setting it in `ng-src` attribute.There are `API`s available in `java script` to help you `encode` and `decode` `URL`s.
Another thing is that if your `JSON` or any entry in `JSON` is malformed you should check you backened code which is generating the `JSON`.

Comment: please how to convert my images in my controller (MainCtrl) to json